# Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, webapi, message-queue

Since I upgraded from Magento 2.2.7 to Magento 2.3.1 I am getting this message in the system.log file:

> main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []

I get this error also on a fresh Magento 2.3.1 install.

Where could I configure or disable it?

Comment: i too have this issue. did you get this sorted out?

Comment: no not yet. not much info on this problem

Comment: Thank you. Please let me know if you find something.

Comment: same issue here...magento 2.3.1 with php7.2

Comment: I too have this issue in magento 2.3.3. did you get this sorted out?

Answer (score 20):

Danila is above is right Solutions that tell you to do cron_run = 'false" will disable other queues you do want, like bulk attribute update or export file generation.

**Option 1 disable packages**

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_WebapiAsync
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Amqp
```

I think it makes sense to disable both as the absence of Ampq allows modules to switch to mysql - but I haven't dug deep into that.  Indeed if all you want is for the error message to vanish then Danila's option is all you need

**Option 2 Tweak your queue cron**, dont disable it

This is if you don't want to or can't take core modules off.

1. List your existing queues

   `bin/magento queue:consumers:list`
2. Add all of them except async to your cron consumer, in env.php. If there is functionality you never use, skip that one (but remember you did...)

```
'queue' => [
    'consumers_wait_for_messages' => 0,
],
'cron_consumers_runner' => [
    'cron_run' => true,
    'max_messages' => 2,
    'single_thread' => true,
    'consumers_wait_for_messages' => 0,
    'consumers' => [
        'product_action_attribute.update',
        'product_action_attribute.website.update',
        'exportProcessor',
        'inventory.source.items.cleanup',
        'inventory.mass.update',
        'inventory.reservations.cleanup',
        'inventory.reservations.update'
    ]
],
```

Most places have a higher max_messages but if you are not having rabbitmq you are possibly on a low budget host too and short queues more often are better. Up the number as you want.

**Option 3 - take things out of Magento's cron and add them manually, queue per queue, to the host system cron**

this implies

`cron_run => false`

and then putting things like   `bin/magento queue:consumers:start   --single-thread  --max-messages=20 inventory.source.items.cleanup` in your cron (or running them manually if you do it rarely. If you have a shared server `'consumers_wait_for_messages' => 0` or consumers-wait-for-messages=1 is key for memory management

Comment: updated for new management parameters

Comment: *`consumers_wait_for_messages`

Comment: you're right @NickRolando in the config file it is consumers_wait_for_messages 
 as a command parameter it is consumers-wait-for-messages

Comment: @iphigenie so that's a typo in the env.php example?

Comment: @Typo yeah, and I had corrected in one place and not both (note: I'm just not sure which location is the one that works so it is in both 'queue' and 'cron_consumers_runner' sections)

Answer (score 18):

The answer from @Rafael Corrêa Gomes (and any to the point that mentions either `'cron_run' => false` or `'consumers' => ['async.operations.all']` in the configuration are quite outrageous because they make many folks copy-paste and destroy their message queues from functioning.

`cron_run` set to `false` in configuration means that the message consumers are not going to be launched by the Magento cron. It means that you will have to run them using other means like SupervisorD or SystemD. And if not (and those answers don't mention that at all), you will have broken stuff beyond words "message queues", which includes, at very minimum, data export in Magento admin.

The documentation that is being referred to when posting such configuration has incorrect heading below this [section](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/mq/manage-message-queues.html#configuration) with words:

> Specific configuration

instead of

> Sample configuration

It is a sample, and not a standard. Neither it is a recommendation to solve anything.

But, while the docs are at fault, it doesn't excuse skipping the lines and not reading further, then posting destructive solutions online.

The real solution is either [disabling the Bulk API](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/how-to-fix-consumer-async-operations-all-skipped-as-required-connection-amqp-is-not-configured-unknown-connection-name-amqp-in-magento-2) which most installations don't use, essentially:

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_WebapiAsync
```

Or, configure RabbitMQ if you want the bulk API (highly unlikely, depends on specific use case).

Comment: I always disable the Magento_Amqp too as I have the idea (perhaps an illusion!) that third party modules might decide to use it, but in its absence can revert to other operation mode. Is it unnecessary to disable it?

Comment: From the looks of it, `Magento_Amqp` will act as a "driver" for `Magento_WebapiAsync`. So by disabling `Magento_Amqp` you're indirectly disabling `Magento_WebapiAsync` as well. For "in its absence can revert to other operation mode" - no, I don't think that's a safe assumption. If we take the `Magento_WebapiAsync` for example, it absolutely wants/needs AMQP/RabbitMQ set up, and cannot function in other operation modes. So the same thing can be assumed for any modules that will rely on `Magento_Amqp`. As in - they will not function when it's disabled.

Comment: Strangely, when only one is disabled I stil get error messages in some scenarios.
Disabling Amqp removes the async.operations.all consumer, disabling WebapiAsync removes a user of the async.operations.all, which from your explanation I understand to be the only one. But I see other modules with async in my tree, who could one day try to use it next update, hence why i worry.

Answer (score 3):

Edit the `/app/etc/env.php` file to configure the cron job `consumers_runner`.

```php
<?php
return [

// ...

    'cron_consumers_runner' => [
        'cron_run' => true,
        'max_messages' => 20000,
        'consumers' => [
            'async.operations.all',
        ]
    ],

]; // return closing
```

To get the list of all your queue consumers that can be configured running:

```
php bin/magento queue:consumers:list
```

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/mq/manage-message-queues.html#configuration

Comment: how is this a solution? you're disabling the async queues

Comment: Hi @AlexBejan, there are two answers, it's enabled by default so disabling is just an option when you don't pretend to use it, you if you want you can use the configuration that I recommended, it's the same as Magento DevDocs recommends.

Comment: I'm not sure what the addition to the env.php does here. If I want to enable async sending of messages, do I add that code or do I edit the cron_run to be true?

Comment: Left the cron_run false @Webninja

Comment: Yes, that I noticed. So if that is left to false Magento does not send emails by cron? Or what is the effect of that setting?

Comment: More details are in the Devdocs reference link, but if it's true the cron will run the consumers_runner and not your configured consumers.

Comment: @Rafael - I tried your method, still my email not receiving from website.

Comment: @Priya, check if the issue is related to your server blocking the email sending. You can also try to use an SMTP extension.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for all your support. I found the error because of SMTP extension not installed.

Comment: what is the fix for it? my cron file is not triggered due to this? how can we overcome with this issue? i need to run my cron file

Comment: Hi @jafarpinjar, here you can see what is the fix for https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/309783/why-do-i-need-rabbitmq/309784#309784

Comment: This answer should have never been upvoted. You will get rid of the message in the log at the cost of breaking many things. See the answer below.

Comment: Hi @DanilaVershinin, I fixed the answer, thank you for reporting it

Comment: @RafaelCorrêaGomes fixed the answer how? By running only the one consumer that has problem? It is still invalid. There shouldn't be answer just for the sake of answer. Better delete it if you continue reading by skipping through the lines and not understanding how your own "solution" works. Pardon my language, but this is the clear example of how damaging answers could be when they are posted without understanding the topic.

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** Create config file in your custom module `{module_vendor}/{module_name}/etc/queue_consumer.xml` with following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework-message-queue:etc/consumer.xsd">
    <consumer name="async.operations.all" connection="db"/>
</config>
```

**Detailed answer:** Magento has default implementation for message queue based on MySQL - `Magento_MysqlMq`. All default Magento modules, which requires message queue processing, uses this MySQL implementation (example: vendor/magento/module-inventory-catalog/etc/queue_consumer.xml) by `connection="db"` for their consumers. But for some reason Magento_WebapiAsync expects RabbitMQ implementation which is available by default in Magento Commerce (maybe this module was developer for Magento Commerce).

So solution is to move this consumer from RabbitMQ (which is unavailable) to MySQL-MQ (which is available by default)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this on Magento 2.3.1 and after some searching through the docs I found this link: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/mq/manage-message-queues.html

Here it explains what it does and it says you can edit the /app/etc/env.php file to configure the cron job consumers_runner. I decided to add this "async.operations.all" consumer here.

Answer (score 0):

For me **Vladyslav Sikailo** answer is right, but my xml is a bit different.
I add attribute queue because Magento give me an error if missing.

This is my *{module_vendor}/{module_name}/etc/queue_consumer.xml* to force using **db** instead of **amqp**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework-message-queue:etc/consumer.xsd">
    <consumer name="async.operations.all" queue="async.operations.all" connection="db"/>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

**communication.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Communication/etc/communication.xsd">
    <topic name="test.import.products" request="string" />
</config>
```

**queue_consumer.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework-message-queue:etc/consumer.xsd">
    <consumer name="TestImportProducts" queue="test_import_products" connection="amqp" handler="Test\Products\Model\Consumer::processProduct"/>
</config>
```

**queue_publisher.xml**

```
    <publisher topic="test.import.products">
        <connection name="amqp" exchange="test-import-products" />
    </publisher>
</config>
```

**queue_topology.xml**

```
    <exchange name="test-import-products" type="topic" connection="amqp">
        <binding id="TestImportProducts" topic="test.import.products" destinationType="queue" destination="test_import_products"/>
    </exchange>
</config>
```

Answer (score -1):

I went with this at the end of app/etc/env.php

```
'cron_consumers_runner' => array(
        'cron_run' => false,
        'max_messages' => 20000,
        'consumers' => array(
            'consumer1',
            'consumer2',
        )
    )
```

Comment: only set cron_run to false if you have setup your own consumer cron process, it will disable the consumer_runner cron task that initiates the consumers.