# Magento_Amqp: Is it safe to disable this module?

Tags: magento2.3.1

Magento_Amqp module is for **Manage message queues** as per https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/mq/manage-message-queues.html.

And **system.log** is continuous display below log.

`Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp`

Is it safe to disable Magento_Amqp module?

Comment: Is no one here who is able to answer this question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269928/consumer-async-operations-all-skipped-as-required-connection-amqp-is-not-con)