# Magento System.log - Unknown connection name amqp [] []

Tags: magento2, cron, system.log

I am following  this documentation for the custom cron job

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cron/custom-cron-tut.html

I should get the below message in the system.log as part of the custom cron job

`[2016-11-02 22:17:03] main.INFO: Cron Works [] []`

but I am having another message along with the one I mentioned above, which is

`[2020-03-03 12:05:03] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []`

Does anybody know what this message is?

This question is duplicate to another which is this
[Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/269928/85429)
but I didn't find the answers as a proper solution/explanation

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at the message queue overview doc?

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/mq/rabbitmq-overview.html

This is what's being confirmed as not configured