# Why do I need RabbitMQ?

Tags: magento2, performance, message-queue, rabbit-mq

Magento 2 offers easy integration to RabbitMQ, but why and when do I need RabbitMQ installed in my store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Making long history short, you need it when you have to optimize the high load operations in Magento 2.

[RabbitMQ](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/install-rabbitmq.html) is a message broker that primarily uses AMQP for processing communications between 2 applications. It is a middleman where Queues can be defined and applications can connect to the Queues to pull the messages. Some tasks might be time-consuming. There would also be a need to handle multiple requests. The message broker puts these tasks into corresponding queues for the other application to process these independently.

[Message Queuing](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/mq/manage-message-queues.html) allows web servers to respond quickly to requests and delegate them to a third party for processing rather than perform the task instantaneously. This helps in handling multiple, resource-intensive requests efficiently.

Reference: [RabbitMQ Magento 2](https://www.egrovesys.com/blog/rabbitmq-magento2/)