# Unknown connection name amqp

Tags: magento2.4

i have a magento 2.4.4 version and i'm bot able to complete checkout for followinmg critical error:

> [2022-04-21 14:46:45] main.CRITICAL: Unknown connection name amqp
> {"exception":"[object] (LogicException(code: 0): Unknown connection
> name amqp at
> /home/web/website/www/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/MessageQueue/ConnectionTypeResolver.php:43)"}
> []

I already tried following

```
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_WebapiAsync
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_Amqp
```

but with no success..
What can i do?

Comment: Follow this url - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/314016/3723 it's help full to you